# How can I analyse the data from UPPAAL simulator eps file?

Tags: analysis, eps, uppaal

I ran the automaton and exported the eps file. But how do I further analyse and get information from eps file? 
Is it possible to write variable values to an external log file?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) there is "export -> comma separated values" menu option when you right-click on the plot, 2) the trajectories are printed on standard output from verifyta (command line tool).

Answer (score 0):

There is no point analysing eps (these are meant to be included into report).
For data analysis try the following in the verifier using `simulate` (Uppaal 4.1) queries like this:

```
simulate 1 [<=300] { 
  (T(1).Ready+2*T(1).Computing+3*T(1).Release+4*T(1).Error)+8,
  (T(2).Ready+2*T(2).Computing+3*T(2).Release+4*T(2).Error)+4,
  (T(3).Ready+2*T(3).Computing+3*T(3).Release+4*T(3).Error)+0
}
```

where `T(i)` is a process and `Ready`, `Computing`, `Release` and `Error` are its  locations. Then model-check the query, right-click on it and see the plot, then:

a) right-click on the plot and choose `Export` -> `comma separated values`,

or:

b) parse the plot values from standard output from verifyta (command line tool) when verifying the query above.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I can try this. Is there a way in UPPAAL to write a log or update a variable value to an external file as the automaton runs?

Comment: no, there is an API for that: http://people.cs.aau.dk/~marius/modeldoc/

Comment: Thank you. I am also looking at interfacing matlab with uppaal for my research.

Comment: @user3559706 I have several partial-solutions to Matlab/Simulink: one SFunction another FMI, please contact for collaboration in August (going on vacations now)